# Show selection from suggestion list in Android searchview

Tags: android, searchview

I have a searchview with suggestion list. If the user selects an item from the list, a new intent is sent and I can apply my filter, but the search view remains empty.

If I update the search view in onNewIntent with setQuery (see below), the effect is that the selected item is shown in the search view, but the suggestion list pops up again. Can I avoid that and only show the current query text within the search view without the suggestion list popping up?

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    final String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    if (!query.equals(searchView.getQuery())) {
    searchView.setQuery(query, false); // makes the suggestions pop up
    }
    applyFilter(query);
}
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The trick is to replace the default behaviour of the search manager by using an onSubmitListener on the search view and returning true from its onSuggestionClick method, rather than calling setQuery(query, false) in the intent handler:

```
@Override
public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
String suggestion = getSuggestion(position);
searchView.setQuery(suggestion, true); // submit query now
return true; // replace default search manager behaviour
}

private String getSuggestion(int position) {
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getItem(
    position);
String suggest1 = cursor.getString(cursor
    .getColumnIndex(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1));
return suggest1;
}
```