# SearchView: Getting the selected item from the suggestion listener

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, simplecursoradapter, searchview, matrixcursor

I have a search view that has the suggestions populated by a MatrixCursor (because I already have an array of Strings). However I would like to get which item is being selected by the user. So far I am only able to get the position where the user has clicked on the suggestion list:

```
searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
            String selectedItem = (String)mAdapter.getItem(position);
            Log.e("search view", selectedItem);
            return true;
        }
```

However I have got an error: android.database.MatrixCursor cannot be cast to java.lang.String
and I am not sure how to go around with it. Really appreciate for any kind of help.

Comment: There is a workaround [here][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424104/show-selection-from-suggestion-list-in-android-searchview

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51141335/8383332

Answer (score 12):

If someone is still looking for the answer. Use this code.

```
searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
        Cursor cursor= searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getCursor();
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String suggestion =cursor.getString(2);//2 is the index of col containing suggestion name.
        searchView.setQuery(suggestion,true);//setting suggestion
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The position brings the suggested list selected item position. If your suggested list is a `Cursor` (from the `Exception` I may think is a `MatrixCursor`), you have to get the item that is in the position of the Cursor.

```
public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
    Cursor searchCursor = mySearchViewAdapter.getCursor();
    if(searchCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        String selectedItem = searchCursor.getString(columnOfTheItemStringInTheMatrix);
    }
}
```

`columnOfTheItemStringInTheMatrix` is the column number that you assigned when you created the Matrix and added the row. For example:

```
MatrixCursor c = new MatrixCursor("item"});
```

and when you added a row (a new item to the MatrixCursor):

```
String item =  "myItem";
c.addRow(new Object[]{item});
```

Then the `columnOfTheItemStringInTheMatrix = 0`;